# ID from DB does not display

Tags: java, database, javafx

could someone tell me, why everything works fine except showing ID in table?? Is there any problem with data type?

There is a code, where I put data into tableView.

```
public class TabulkaProdukty {

    private final FlowPane panelTabulky;
    public final TableView<Produkty> tabulkaTabulkaProdukty;
    public ObservableList<Produkty> dataTabulkaProdukty;
    public static Connection connection;
    private static Statement statement;

    public TabulkaProdukty() {
        panelTabulky = new FlowPane();
        tabulkaTabulkaProdukty = new TableView<>();
        panelTabulky.getChildren().add(tabulkaTabulkaProdukty);
        tabulkaTabulkaProdukty.setEditable(true);
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:produkty");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("create table if not exists produkty(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, nazev TEXT NOT NULL, popis TEXT NOT NULL, typ TEXT NOT NULL, cena TEXT NOT NULL);");
            dataTabulkaProdukty = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM produkty;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                dataTabulkaProdukty.add(new Produkty(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("nazev"), rs.getString("popis"), rs.getString("typ"), rs.getString("cena")));
            }

            // VECI V TABULCE
            TableColumn idCol = new TableColumn("id");
            idCol.setMinWidth(50);
            idCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));

            TableColumn nazevCol = new TableColumn("Název");
            nazevCol.setMinWidth(100);
            nazevCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("nazev"));

            TableColumn popisCol = new TableColumn("Popis");
            popisCol.setMinWidth(200);
            popisCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("popis"));

            TableColumn typCol = new TableColumn("Typ");
            typCol.setMinWidth(50);
            typCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("typ"));

            TableColumn cenaCol = new TableColumn("Cena");
            cenaCol.setMinWidth(50);
            cenaCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("cena"));

            tabulkaTabulkaProdukty.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
            tabulkaTabulkaProdukty.setItems(null);
            tabulkaTabulkaProdukty.setItems(dataTabulkaProdukty);
            tabulkaTabulkaProdukty.getColumns().addAll(idCol, nazevCol, popisCol, typCol, cenaCol);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Chyba databáze");
            alert.setContentText("Nepovedlo se načíst data z databáze.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

    }
```

There is a Class Produkty

```
public class Produkty implements Serializable {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty id;
        private final SimpleStringProperty nazev;
        private final SimpleStringProperty popis;
        private final SimpleStringProperty typ;
        private final SimpleStringProperty cena;
        public NaMinimum panelNaMinimum;

        public Produkty(int pID, String pNazev, String pPopis, String pTyp, String pCena) {
            this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(pID);
            this.nazev = new SimpleStringProperty(pNazev);
            this.popis = new SimpleStringProperty(pPopis);
            this.typ = new SimpleStringProperty(pTyp);
            this.cena = new SimpleStringProperty(pCena);
        }

        public int getIDProduktu() {return id.get();}
        public void setIDProduktu(int pID) {id.set(pID);} 
        public String getNazev() {return nazev.get();}
        public void setNazev(String pNazev) {nazev.set(pNazev);}
        public String getPopis() {return popis.get();}
        public void setPopis(String pPopis) {popis.set(pPopis);}
        public String getTyp() {return typ.get();}
        public void setTyp(String pTyp) {typ.set(pTyp);}
        public String getCena() {return cena.get();}
        public void setCena(String pCena) {cena.set(pCena);}

    }
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion of solve.

Comment: I added it into question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PropertyValueFactory` looks for methods based on the constructor parameter, not for fields. Based on the name of the getter, the parameter should be `"IDProduktu"` or `"iDProduktu"`:

```
idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("IDProduktu"));
```

Note that without property getter methods `TableView` cannot observe any changes in the property. You could use plain fields in this case for the same effect. To observe changes, you need to provide a method named `<property>Property` where `<property>` is a placeholder for the name of the property as passed to the constructor of `PropertyValueFactory`, e.g. in case you use `"id"` as constructor parameter:

```
public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but I still do not know, how to implement it into my code. Could you please try to implement it?

Comment: @HonzíkAzjolHavelka Implement what? The first code snippet could be used to replace the similar statement in your `TabulkaProdukty` constructor (`idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));`) and the second code snippet can alternatively be pasted to the body of the `Produkty` class (in this case keeping `idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));`)...

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to know what you're doing with this, but my guess is that the integer value of id is not being shown as a string and therefore not acting in the same way as the other parameters.

Comment: Well, I am trying to get values from database into table and display it. I have same guess like you, but I am so bad in java programming. This is a bit copied from working example and I do not know, what am I doing to be honest. It is stupid homework.